# Filtering an Array of Objects using Jquery $.grep without an Object Wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

Filtering works fine for an object (`data`) wrapping around an array of objects:

```
var arr = {"data":
 [
  {"name":"Alan","height":"171","weight":"66"},
  {"name":"Ben","height":"182","weight":"90"},
  {"name":"Chris","height":"163","weight":"71"}
 ]
};

var new_arr = $.extend(true, arr);

new_arr.data = $.grep(new_arr.data, function(n, i){
  return n.weight > 70;
});

alert(new_arr.data.length); // answer is 2
```

However, filtering without the object wrapper doesn't.

```
var arr = [
  {"name":"Alan","height":"171","weight":"66"},
  {"name":"Ben","height":"182","weight":"90"},
  {"name":"Chris","height":"163","weight":"71"}
 ];

var new_arr = $.extend(true, arr);

new_arr = $.grep(new_arr, function(n, i){
  return n.weight > 70;
});

alert(new_arr.length); // answer is 1 instead of 2
```

I am not sure where is the problem. Can anyone point out. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) incorrectly. You can't extend the new_arr with an array. Extend will add methods/props to an object but what methods/props will it create when it runs into your array? This is why it works with the object wrapper: 1) extend expects an object and 2) 'data' is a property that can be added to new_arry.

Despite, in your second example, it doesn't look like you need to extend anything. Does this work?

```
new_arr = $.grep(arr, function(n, i){ // just use arr
  return n.weight > 70;
});
```

Comment: I just found out the reason too :) I forgot why I used extend in the first place. It seems I don't need it now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to a object more deep,

```
var prodIds = [];

        $.grep(this.prodOrders, function (n, i) { 

            $.grep(n.ProductionOrderLines, function (n2, i2) { 
                if (n2.ItemNo == resource) {
                    prodIds.push(n2.DocumentAbsoluteEntry);
                }
            });
        });
```